# convert .key to .pem

Tags: php, encryption, key, private

I need to encrypt with private key and I'm attempting to do so with the following code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("file.key");

$plaintext = "14d9df79-8c4c-4380-8444-d31e1fd3f78a";

openssl_private_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $content);

$transfer = base64_encode($encrypted);

echo "text encrypted is:" . $transfer;  //encrypted string
```

I'm getting the error:
openssl_private_encrypt(): key param is not a valid private key in

Do I have to do something to the key file? It is binary.

Comment: You mention that your key is not in pem format, how did you come by this file? What PHP code did you use to create the key?

Comment: the .key file was sent by another entity which elaborated it

Comment: SORRY, i correct, i generate this key file

Comment: with an app given by the other office

Answer (score 3):

First, try converting a key into PEM format using openssl:

```
openssl rsa -inform der -in file.key -outform pem -out filekey.pem
```

Next, extract the private key from the PEM file using [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php)

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("filekey.pem"));

$plaintext = "14d9df79-8c4c-4380-8444-d31e1fd3f78a";

openssl_private_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $key);

$transfer = base64_encode($encrypted);

echo "text encrypted is:" . $transfer;  //encrypted string
```

Comment: I was just about to post that function Martin, it was already in my clipboard :)

Comment: ...but user1873420 has already pointed out that the file is not in .pem format (required for openssl_pkey_get_private)

Comment: I tried what you said and it is the same message: openssl_private_encrypt(): key param is not a valid private key in... I saw some examples and they use a key file not in binary, but in pem format. THat is the question, how I can convert my key file in binary into a pem file, the one with text visible characters. thanks mario

Comment: @user1873420: what php function exports a key in binary format? i cannot find it?

Comment: the .key file was given to me. It is suppose to be the private key.

Comment: @user1873420 I have modified my answer

Comment: SORRY, I generate this .key file

Comment: I tried, open rsa -inform der -in file.key -outform pem -out filekey.pem and it is telling me "Unable to load Private Key" what does this mean????

Comment: Most likely this means that the key is not a DER encoded RSA key. There are a few other options to try as @symcbean has suggested. There is also DSA. You should read the OpenSSL documentation and consult the documentation for your other application to figure out how to convert your key into PEM format.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any x509 file format using a .key extension. There's pem (which is the format you need to load into openssl), DER (files may have .der, .crt or .cer extension) or PKCS#12 (.pfx .p12). It's *probably* DER or PKCS#12:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in file.key -out file.pem -nodes
```

...converts a PKCS#12 to file.pem,

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in file.key -out file.pem
```

...converts a DER file. They'll report an error if it's the wrong file format. OTOH you could just use the 'file' command to find out the file type. (this is assuming that you've got a Posix / Linux system - you didn't say).

Or you could just ask the person who gave it to you what format it is.

Comment: all inf given to me is x.509 certificate version 3, does this clear my doubt?

Comment: No - x509 is not a file format - it defines the data stored in the file. Like the difference between a Word processor document and a .doc file.

Comment: SORRY, i generated this .key file

Comment: the first sent lots of errors, the second sent "Unable to load certificate", I've already aske the other office the format of the .key file, which its the private key (I generated it)

Answer (score -2):

Solved
I just use the

openssl pkcs8 .....

command

hope this is useful to someone else